# Jquery Mobile/Phonegap Swipe Gesture issue in Android

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have the following code for swipe right event in jquery mobile/phonegap app.Code is working fine, but problem is i have to swipe 3-4 times to get response on android device.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Slider Stop</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("swiperight", "#listitem", function() {
                $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                        <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>
                    Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your document and device are both ready. I suggest this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Slider Stop</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onBodyLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
            // set your swipe threshold explicitly
            $.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold = 120;
            $(document).on("swiperight", "#listitem", function() {
                $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
            });
        }

    </script>
</head> 
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
      ...
```

Comment: You might also consider upgrading to the latest versions of jQuery Mobile and jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @roviuser, First solution didn't worked but upgrading jquery mobile and jquery worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in JQM that has been resolved but is not yet implemented https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5534

Basically the min distance measured by the swipe event must take into account the pixel density of the device. So in JQM's case, the following change to touch.js will solve the issue:

```
horizontalDistanceThreshold = window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 15 : 30;
verticalDistanceThreshold = window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 15 : 30;
```